# List all files older than x days only in current directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am new to unix and couldn't get appropriate outcome in other questions.

I want to list only files in current directory which are older than x days. I have below restriction

- List only files in current folder which are older than 30
  days
- Output shouldn't include directories and subdirectories
- This should list files similar as "ls" command does
- Output should look like `file1 file2 file3 ..`

I used `find . -mtime +30`. but this gives files and files in sub-directories as well. I would like to restrict doing search recursively and not to search inside directories.

Thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: Take a look at `man find`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `find . -maxdepth 1` to exclude subdirectories.

Comment: find: unknown predicate `-maxdepth=1'

Answer (score 25):

You can do this:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -print
```

If having problems, do:

```
find ./ -depth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -print
```

Comment: And if `find` isn't installed? Is there nothing with just `ls` and `stat` ?

Answer (score 14):

To add on @Richasantos's answer:

This works perfectly fine

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30
```

Prints:

```
./file1
./file2
./file3
```

You can now pipe this to anything you want. Let's say you want to remove all those old files:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -print | xargs /bin/rm -f
```

From `man find`: ``

> If you are piping the output of find into another program and there is the faintest possibility that the files which you are searching for might contain a newline, then you should seriously consider using the `-print0` option instead of `-print`.

So using `-print0`

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -print0
```

Prints (with null characters in between):

```
./file1./file2./file3
```

And is used like this to remove those old files:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime +30 -print0 | xargs -0 /bin/rm -f
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different spin on this: `find` is incredibly versatile, you can specify size and time as follows:

This finds you all the logs that are 4 months or older and bigger than 1 meg.
If you remove the + sign, it finds files that are roughly that size.

```
find /var/log -type f -mtime +120 -size +1M
/var/log/anaconda/journal.log
/var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.23
/var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.22
/var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.24
/var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.25
/var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.21
/var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.20
/var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.19
```

What's even better, you can feed this into an `ls`:

```
find /var/log -type f -mtime +120 -size +1M -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lh
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M Oct  1 13:24 /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.19
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M Sep 27 07:44 /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.20
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M Sep 22 03:32 /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.21
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M Sep 16 23:23 /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.22
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M Sep 11 19:12 /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.23
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M Sep  6 15:02 /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.24
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.6M Sep  1 10:51 /var/log/ambari-agent/ambari-alerts.log.25
-rw-------. 1 root root 1.8M Mar 11  2019 /var/log/anaconda/journal.log
```